# Intersect Bottom of the screen android

Tags: java, android, rect

I have objects that are infinitely falling from the top of the screen to the bottom, and when they reach the bottom I want to delete them. They are stored in a `ArrayList` so removing them is easy, I just can't seem to figure out how to detect them intersecting the bottom of the screen using `RectF`.

Basically all I need is an imaginary line across the bottom.

Is that possible to do like this?

`stickArr.get(i).getStick().intersect(a, b, c, d)//I don't exactly understand what to put into intersect`

Comment: check if object's 'y' is greater then or equal to bottom 'y' of the screen.

Comment: I was doing that, but for some reason the remove method did not work, but it does work when two objects intersect I've found. I'll try again.

Comment: @AkshayBhat thank you, my game works now. I don't know why it didn't before.

Comment: create a rect where top of the rect should be bottom of the screen

Comment: great no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

intersect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)

If the rectangle specified by left,top,right,bottom intersects this rectangle, return true and set this rectangle to that intersection, otherwise return false and do not change this rectangle.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html#intersect(float, float, float, float)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html#intersect%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29)